# How to run a PHP script using a DreamHost Cron Job

Tags: php, shell, cron, dreamhost

I have a php script that I'd like to run everyday on my DreamHost website using a cron job. I've tested the script manually so I know it works properly.

I've tried setting up the cron job with this command line:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null "http://www.mysite.org/cronjobs/cronjob.php"
```

along with a few other methods including this one as well:

```
/dh/cgi-system/php54.cgi /home/username/mysite.org/cronjobs/cronjob.php
```

None of these have worked and even worse, I have not received any email with the results so I have no way of knowing what went wrong.

Any idea you may have as to what isn't working would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in the cpanel.

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php /home/username/mysite.org/cronjobs/cronjob.php
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but since here is still no "solution" for users that might look here for a wget example here is how it works at DreamHost:

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.domain.com/path-to-be-called
```